# ModuleNotFound even though folder is present

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to build a runner.py file that will help me debug my spider code. THe runner.py file is supposed to be used with the Debug function is Visual Studio, take me to my "dogbreeds" spider, and run through the dogbreeds spider code line by line. Here is the runner.py file code I have:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from **puppyfind**.spiders.dogbreeds import dogbreedsSpider

process = CrawlerProcess(settings = get_project_settings())
process.crawl(dogbreedsSpider)
process.start()
```

The issue I have is that my runner.py file is giving me a ModuleNotFound error and saying the module "puppyfind" (bolded above) can not be found.

I checked my active directories by running "import sys" and "print(sys.path)" in the scrapy shell. Which confirms that "C:\Users\UserName\projects\puppyfind" is  is one of the active directories. Inside this folder is where you should find the sub-folder "puppyfind", and this is where I'm getting the ModuleNotFound error.

Here is the exact error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'puppyfind'
File "C:\Users\UserName\projects\puppyfind\puppyfind\runner.py", line 11, in <module>
    from puppyfind.spiders.dogbreeds import dogbreedsSpider
```

I've added the results of the "print(sys.path)" below. Here is the project structure:
[image: Folder Structure]

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: ['C:\\Users\\UserName\\Anaconda3\\envs\\virtual_workspace\\Scripts',                'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Anaconda3\\envs\\virtual_workspace\\python37.zip',           'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Anaconda3\\envs\\virtual_workspace\\DLLs',                   'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Anaconda3\\envs\\virtual_workspace\\lib',                    'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Anaconda3\\envs\\virtual_workspace',

Comment: 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Anaconda3\\envs\\virtual_workspace\\lib\\site-packages',     'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Anaconda3\\envs\\virtual_workspace\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',                                                                              'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Anaconda3\\envs\\virtual_workspace\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',

Comment: 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Anaconda3\\envs\\virtual_workspace\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',                                                                          'C:\\Users\\UserName\\projects\\puppyfind',                                        'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Anaconda3\\envs\\virtual_workspace\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions']

Comment: Hard to tell from your comments: did you try adding the path with puppyfind directly to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?

Comment: @DanielJunglas I did (not mentioned in comments) but I’m not sure I did it correctly. I added two lines in the beginning of the runner.py file that say “import sys” and “sys.path.insert(0,“/puppyfind/“)” which did not seem to help...

Comment: I think setting `sys.path` in the script may be too late. Try setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment globally before you start your script.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @DanielJunglas! While I didn't add it to the setting.py file, I realized I had to add the following lines to my code: "import sys" and "sys.path.append("c:\\Users\\Argin\\projects\\puppyfind\\")"

Comment: I think `from spiders.dogbreeds import dogbreedsSpider` should work?

Comment: Hi @RahulGoswami you are correct! I was getting an unrelated error and thought this line was the issue. I fixed the error in a different way (see my answer below) but thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix the issue by adding the following to the beginning of my code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("c:\\Users\\Username\\projects\\puppyfind\\")
```

I read a lot of places that the syntax of the second line should just be a portion of the path, but that did not work for me. Adding the full path to the append statement made everything work.